# Why squizlabs/php_codesniffer marked as error code with(new Vote)?

Tags: laravel, phpcodesniffer

I laravel 9 project with squizlabs/php_codesniffer my phpstorm 2021 shows error :

```
Expected parameter of type '\TValue', 'Vote' provided
```

in model when I use table name in scope condition :

```
class QuizQualityResult extends Model
{
    protected $table       = 'quiz_quality_results';

    public function scopeGetByVoteCategories($query, $voteCategoryId= null)
    {
        // “new Vote” is marked as error
        $voteTable = with(new Vote)->getTable(); 
        if (!empty($voteCategoryId)) {
            if ( is_array($voteCategoryId) ) {
                $query->whereIn( $voteTable . '.vote_category_id', $voteCategoryId);
            } else {
                $query->where( $voteTable . ' . vote_category_id', $voteCategoryId);
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

If there is a way to fix this error ? Or maybe to use better syntax here ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for helper with() here

```
$voteTable = (new Vote())->getTable()
```

Ps: there is a feeling that your method does not work the way you intended. Perhaps you meant to do the following (I could be wrong):

```
public function scopeGetByVoteCategories($query, $voteCategoryId = null)
{
    if (empty($voteCategoryId)) {
        return $query;
    }

    return $query->whereHas('vote', static function ($query) use ($voteCategoryId) {
        if (is_array($voteCategoryId)) {
            return $query->whereIn('vote_category_id', $voteCategoryId);
        }

        return $query->where('vote_category_id', $voteCategoryId);
    });
}

public function vote()
{
    // your relationship
}
```